# function of the stomp.py heartbeats parameter

Tags: python, timeout, activemq-classic, load-balancing, stomp

Heartbeats are mentioned [here](http://jasonrbriggs.github.io/stomp.py/api.html?highlight=heartbeat#dealing-with-disconnects) in reference to dealing with disconnects.

What does this parameter do exactly? Is it sending packets to the AMQ host, then waiting for them back?

I've tried setting this parameter to `heartbeats=(4000, 4000)`, however I still get disconnected from a load balancer after it's `Idle Timeout` is reached.

Answer (score 1):

This is answered in the [STOMP specification](http://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#Heart-beating).